# C# Non-standard JSON parsing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an oddly formulated JSON response string in this format:

```
 {
  "Result": <this is the array of Ticket objects>,
  "IsLastPage": true,
  "NextSkip": 1,
  "NextTake": 1,
  "PageCount": 2,
  "TotalCount": 3,
  "QueryResultHash": "sample string 4"
}
```

Usually I would access the Json array (the Result value above) when the array is the only thing being returned, like so:

```
var jsonArray = JArray.Parse(resultString); 
foreach (var jsonObject in jsonArray)
{ ... }
```

But I am not sure how to break down the above string so that I can get the 7 values individually and parse the array. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean that usually you get the array as the only item in the json?

Comment: Is that what the json actually looks like? I.E `<this is the array of Ticket objects>` is the actual value?

Comment: No, the array is a correctly formulated string like: {"Id":4412,"Rev":30,"Fields":{"System"... and I mean usually as in the past when I last worked with JSON

Comment: That JSON looks perfectly standard to me.  Instead of `JArray.Parse(...)`, just use `JObject.Parse(...)`.  (Also: if it isn't 'standard JSON', then it isn't *valid* JSON.)

Comment: Or use `JToken.Parse()` and then [`SelectTokens()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm).  But, to confirm, can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing an actual example of the value of the `"Result"` property?

Comment: I will upload it shortly.

Comment: @sd_dracula `{"Id":4412,"Rev":30,"Fields":{"System"...` is not an array, or part of an array, nor does it contain an array. Is that the problem?

Comment: Please show us the complete json with contents of `Result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I would use the library Newtonsoft.Json (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

Then you can create a ResponseContainer class. Something like,

```
//generated by http://json2csharp.com/
public class ResponseContainer
{
    public List<object> Result { get; set; }
    public bool IsLastPage { get; set; }
    public int NextSkip { get; set; }
    public int NextTake { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public string QueryResultHash { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
ResponseContainer response = serializer.Deserialize<ResponseContainer>(jsonString);
```

Now you can access the fields in the json response as a C# object.

Comment: You could use this site [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to get a good idea of what your model or container is going to look like

Comment: Nice, that's a pretty handy tool. I'll edit the generated code in.